# Three pairs of box whisker plots in one coordinate system

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to plot in Excel 2007 something which looks like this:

[image]

Basically I want to plot 2 box whisker plots, then have some empty space and then again 2 box whisker plots, followed by empty space and another 2 box whisker diagrams.
Also I want to have 3 red lines going to each of the box whisker pair, where the position is defined on different values.

I would be very thankful for any assistance. A dummy file with this structure would be great!

Regards,
Excelactuary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do in Excel, as long as you have your data well organized.  Here's how you do it (for detailed instructions, check out [Jon Peltier's excellent blog](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-box-and-whisker-diagrams-box-plots/)):

1. Layout your data similar to how you want it presented on your chart.  Based upon your sample, I organized my data into 6 columns, with a blank column between each pair.
2. Calculate your summary statistics for the data (min, max, med, and quartiles).
3. Calculate the difference between the summary stats for plotting.

   Here's what the data looks like so far:

   [image: Data Layout]
4. Next create a blank Stacked Column Chart (this way Excel doesn't try to overthink it for you).
5. Add your data series for the boxes, formatting the bottom series (Q1) as No Fill/No Outline.
6. Add error bars for the whiskers.

   Adding your red lines across two series is a little tricker.  You'll want to use an additional data series, but as an XY/Scatter chart to create these lines.
7. Add another data series using the Y values (from the bottom of the sample data in the example).
8. Select that series and change it's chart type to XY/Scatter.
9. Edit the data series to include the proper X Values. These are off-set by .5 to appear directly between your data series.
10. Add error bars to this data series.
11. Delete the vertical error bars.
12. Format the horizontal error bars to your need.
13. Format the data series Marker Options to None.

Here's what the final product looks like:

[image]

**EDIT:**  [You can get a sample workbook here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9psh45q3pfqzqc/Clustered%20Box%20Charts_SU.xlsx).

Comment: This looks great dav! Could you share your excel file with me?

Comment: How did you manage to generate the gaps between the pairs of columns?

Comment: I'll link the file later, but the gaps come from the blank columns in the data. So, Excel plots A, B, blank, C, D, blank, E, F.

Comment: When I insert a blank column between B and C for instance, the whiskers from F disappear. How could I fix this?

Comment: Hello dav! I haven't managed to solve the thing with the gaps.

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  Linked a sample workbook for you.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I've managed to get it done with your help and the website you've linked!

Answer (score 0):

[Here are step-by-step instructions on how to make a Box-and-Whisker plot in Excel.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/boxandwhisker-charts-for-excel.html) (this assumes you already have the calculated values, which can be done with Excel's Data Analysis tool) However, adding your red lines may not be possible. If it's the median of the two adjacent plots, you can just use that value in place of the individual plots' medians and set the border to red: that will put a red line in the right place, but it won't extend past the edges of the adjacent plots.

---

Summary of the link: Prepare your data into the following statistics: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuMce.jpg) Note that in this particular case, we'd have columns B and C populated, D blank to leave space on the graph, E and F with more data, G blank, and the H and I with data. Insert a stacked chart of Q1, Median Q1, and Q3 Median. Select the Q1 data and add Error Bars. Format them with a minus-shaped cap, and set the error amount to the Q1-Minimum cells. Do similar steps to get the upper whiskers. Set the fill of the bottom section (Q1) to "no fill", and give the other sections black borders with white fill.

Comment: Please include essential parts of the linked article in your answer, then add attribution to the original source. This way even if the link dies, your answer will still be useful.

Comment: It's a 7 page link which was why I was hesitant initially, but point taken. I'll transcribe the major bits when I have an opportunity tonight.